# How do I write in Chinese, you look well today, as in good colour in face?

Tags: traditional-characters

I visited an auntie in hospital, I want to text her to say she looked well today, how do I write this?

Comment: I would say 你今天看上去气色很好

Comment: 你今天面色/脸色/气色很好. Sometimes, 肤色 works as well.

Answer (score 4):

你今天气色很好！
(Nǐ jīntiān qìsè hěn hǎo!)
You looked well today.

加油，早日康复！ 
(Jiāyóu, zǎorì kāngfù!)
Keep it up, get well soon!